# C++: Get 1D array from Multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, c, arduino, function-call

I have this defined:

```
int zinc[] =        {D3,         180,        30,         5,          0,          15};
int omega[] =       {D2,         180,        40,         0,          0,          30};
int magnesium[] =   {D1,         180,        30,         5,          0,          15};



int order[] = {*zinc, *omega, *magnesium};
```

calling

```
dispense(zinc);
```

works, calling

```
dispense(order[1]);
```

does not.

I think I am missing only one char.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: problem doesn't seem related to arduino, and probably each order element should better be a `struct&` than an `int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this call

```
dispense(zinc);
```

the argument expression has an array type.

In this call

```
dispense(order[1]);
```

the argument expression has the type `int`.

So argument expressions have different incompatible types.

It seems you mean the following declaration

```
int * order[] = { zinc, omega, magnesium};
```

instead of that

```
int order[] = {*zinc, *omega, *magnesium};
```

In this case these two calls

```
dispense(zinc);
```

and

```
dispense(order[1]);
```

will be identical provided that the function does not accept an array by reference.

In any case you have no multi-dimensional array. In the above declaration you have an array of pointers to first elements of the arrays used as initializers. Nevertheless you can access integer objects stored in arrays applying two subscript operators as for example

```
order[i][j]
```